# What should the return type be when the function might not have a value to return?

Tags: c++

In the old days, you might have a function like this:

```
const char* find_response(const char* const id) const;
```

If the item could not be found, then a null could be returned to indicate the fact, otherwise obviously return the relevant string.

But when the function is changed to:

```
const std::string& find_response(const std::string& id) const;
```

What do you return to indicate item not found?

Or should signature really be:

```
bool find_response(const std::string& id, std::string& value) const;
```

What would be the most elegant modern C++ way?

Comment: Something wrong with `const std::string*`?

Comment: I think it's a good question, but maybe the title is a bit misleading..

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't think I have EVER used a std::string*.  I don't see a good reason to change the habit.  Maybe use a reference.

Comment: @user619818 There's this saying that goes thus: if you look at old code and see nothing worth changing, it means you did not learn enough in the meantime.

Comment: Avoid returning references.

Comment: @n.m. ? Could you elaborate what's wrong with returning references? `operator[]` does it. Or do you mean returning references to local variables (definitely wrong)? Or...? (I ask because general statement like this can hardly help anyone)

Comment: `operator[]` has no choice, it has to mimic the builtin operator `[]` (which IMHO it should not have done but we are stuck with that design decision). Your code has no such obligations. Returning by value is more robust and loss of performance is negligible.

Comment: @n.m. Still too general. There are areas of coding where no loss of performance is not ever negligible in no way. Trust me.

Comment: @n.m. So you mean "Return by value by default, unless you know you want references"? Well I agree with that rule (especially now, when multi-threading is common)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What would be the most elegant modern C++ way?

There's, as always, not just one solution to this problem.

If you decide to go for any solution that references the original resonse instance, you're on a slippery road when it comes to aliasing and memory management, especially in a multi threaded environment. By copying the response to the caller, no such issues arises.

Today, I would do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string> find_response(const std::string& id) const;
```

That way, you can check for `nullptr` as "in the olden days" **and** it's 100% clear who's responsibility it is to clear up the returned instance: the caller.

The only downside I see of this, is the additional copy of the response string, but don't dismiss that as a downside until measured and proven so.

Another way is to do as is done when searching `std::set<>` and `std::map<>` - return a `std::pair<bool, const char*>` where one value is `bool is_found` and the other is `const char* response`. That way you don't get the "overhead" of the additional response copy, only of the returned `std::pair<>` which is likely to be maximally optimized by the compiler.

Comment: *"The only downside I see of this..."* - And using dynamic memory allocation for a perfect value type is not a downside? -1 - But ok, +1 for the `std::pair` solution.

Comment: @ChristianRau: *"... is the additional copy of the response string"* - the memory for that additional copy (of the `const char*` data) *is* dynamically allocated and that's my point. What was your point?

Comment: @Johannn Huh? I'm talking about the use of a dynamically allocated object for what could just have been a statically allocated object. I'm not talking about the copy of the underlying string, that a `std::string` return value would have done, too. It's not the copy that is rubbish, but the dynamically allocated object of a pure value type class. If that was really meant by your *"additional copy"* sentence, then I didn't get it from that.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I see what you mean now. Everyone cannot (aren't allowed to) use 3rd party libs like `boost`. In lieu of `optional` in the current `std`, `std::unique_ptr<>` can convey the same semantics as returning a pointer to the internal response string and overload `nullptr` as "doesn't exist".

Comment: @ChristianRau: To answer your question *"And using dynamic memory allocation for a perfect value type is not a downside?"* - depends on the **semantics**, as described in the previous sentence. If there's no semantic point of it, then I wouldn't do it. If there's semantic meaning to it and it's not a proven bottleneck, then I see much less problem with it and prefer to worry about bigger issues.

Comment: I agree that `std::unique_ptr` is one of many viable solutions with some advantages over other solutions (and I'm the last one to prefer a third-party solution over a standard library solution anyway). It was just the suppression of one of its most important conceptual disadvantages that caught my attention. But I might also agree that it may be subjective how far this shift in semantics disturbs one's inner peace.

Comment: +1 for "There's, as always, not just one solution to this problem."

Answer (score 22):

[`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional). It was specifically designed for this kind of situation.

<strike>Note, it will be included in upcoming C++14 standard as `std::optional`.</strike> Update: After reviewing national body comments to N3690, `std::optional` was voted out from C++14 working paper into a separate Technical Specification. It is not a part of the draft C++14 as of n3797.

Compared to `std::unique_ptr`, it avoids dynamic memory allocation, and expresses more clearly its purpose. `std::unique_ptr` is better for polymorphism (e.g. factory methods) and storing values in containers, however.

Usage example:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/none.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

class A
{
private:
    std::string value;
public:
    A(std::string s) : value(s) {}

    boost::optional<std::string> find_response(const std::string& id) const
    {
        if(id == value)
            return std::string("Found it!");
        else
            return boost::none;
        //or
        //return boost::make_optional(id == value, std::string("Found it!"));
    }

    //You can use boost::optional with references,
    //but I'm unfamiliar with possible applications of this.
    boost::optional<const std::string&> get_id() const
    {
        return value;
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    A a("42");
    boost::optional<std::string> response = a.find_response("42"); //auto is handy
    if(response)
    {
        std::cout << *response;
    }
}
```

Comment: C++14 is interesting but not something I can use right now (given work environment).

Comment: @user619818 It's also in Boost. (if you are allowed to use it)

Answer (score 3):

If the function is returning a string by reference, but needs the ability to indicate that no such string exists, the most obvious solution is to return a pointer, which is basically a reference that can be null, i.e. *exactly* what was sought after.

```
const std::string* find_response(const std::string& id) const;
```

Comment: or a boost::optional<string>

Comment: but I see what your good point is here. and yes, I should have said string& not string

Comment: I have actually come round to agreeing that this isn't such a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are several good solutions here already. But for the sake of completeness I'd like to add this one. If you don't want to rely on `boost::optional` you may easily implement your own class like

```
class SearchResult
{
    SearchResult(std::string stringFound, bool isValid = true)
        : m_stringFound(stringFound),
        m_isResultValid(isValid)
    { }

    const std::string &getString() const { return m_stringFound; }
    bool isValid() const { return m_isResultValid; }

private:
    std::string m_stringFound;
    bool m_isResultValid;
};
```

Obviously your method signature looks like this then

```
const SearchResult& find_response(const std::string& id) const;
```

But basically that's the same as the boost solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use of pointers in C++ is forgiven if you need to return a nullable entity. This is widely accepted. 
But of course `bool find_response(const std::string& id, std::string& value) const;` is quite verbose. So it is a matter of your choice.

Answer (score -2):

I think the second way is better. Or you can write like this:

```
int find_response(const std::string& id, std::string& value) const;
```

if this function return -1, it tells that you don't find the response.

Comment: And why on earth would an `int` return with a magic `-1` error value be in any way better than a `bool` return? This is *C++* and not *C*.