# unordered_map: what to return if key is not in map?

Tags: c++, semantics, unordered-map

As a preface to this question, I have to say that I am a Java programmer and therefore much more accustomed to the semantics of Maps in Java than in C++.  In Java it is quite common and expected get `null` returned when looking up a key in the Map. I am translating some of our code to c++, and trying to find the c++ way of doing things when interacting with an unordered_map.

Specifically I have a class which contains an unordered_map. Instead of exposing the map directly to client code, I have 2 wrapper functions, one to put key/value pair into the map, and one to retrieve the value for specified key, i.e:

```
void set_tag_value(string tag, string value);

string& get_tag_value(string tag);
```

If I use `unordered_map.at()` to retrieve the value, then it will throw an Exception which my code would need to catch, or alternatively, allow it propagate to the client code.  (Propagating the exception to the seems unfriendly to me, though).

Maybe an alternative would be to change the return value to a `string*` type, and return NULL if not found (which is the Java way of doing it), but then user needs to check for NULL (which is also not so friendly).

So my question has two parts:

1. What is developer-friendly way to handle the failed look up, and what return value would be useful (exception, NULL, empty string, or something else)?
2. Inside my code, which map look up method is more typical to use when you expect it might not find the key, at() and catch exception, or find and check iterator == map.end()? (This part of the question is me just trying to learn the c++ way of doing things).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: `boost::optional` or `std::optional` (C++14). [More details in my answer here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061955/what-should-the-return-type-be-when-the-function-might-not-have-a-value-to-retur/17062103#17062103)

Comment: The "C++ way" would be to give the client access to the full interface of the unordered_map, so they can (for example) apply standard algorithms to it via its iterators.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I often feel uncomfortable giving direct access to class internal data structures, unless I feel that there is some functional use case for the client code to access it as an object.  Certainly in Java, I have often found that as code evolves, I change the underlying data structures, and so anything bound to them has to be recompiled as well.  In this instance, clients should not care how the mappings are stored, they just need to be able to retrieve values (and not have an error if a value is not found).

Comment: @SamGoldberg: The point is that an `unordered_map` already provides a fairly abstract interface that's functional and well-designed. More importantly, everybody who knows C++ already knows how to user it. About all you're accomplishing by hiding it is creating another (less capable) interface for your users to learn.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my opinion it's best not to return pointers to the contents of a map that you're keeping private since the pointers may be invalidated if the map changes.

I would have the function return a success code (`bool`) and pass a reference to a string to actually return the value in if found. For example,

```
bool get_tag_value(const string& tag, string& value)
{
    auto t = my_map.find(tag);
    if (t == my_map.end()) return false;
    value = t->second;
    return true;
}
```

Note that while `unordered_map::at()` will throw if the key is not found, `unordered_map::find()` returns an invalid iterator (`unordered_map::end()`) - so you can avoid handling exceptions this way.

If you want to stick with returning a string, then simply return an empty string (`return string();`) if the key isn't found.

Answer (score 1):

These are the 2 options I would consider depending on your willingness to use boost:

**Return a pointer:**

```
/* const? */ string* get_tag_value_ptr(const string& tag)
{
    auto it = theMap.find(tag);
    if (it != theMap.end()) {
        return &it->second;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

**Return an optional reference:**

```
boost::optional</* const? */ string&> get_tag_value_opt(const string& tag)
{
    auto it = theMap.find(tag);
    if (it != theMap.end()) {
        return it->second;
    }

    return boost::none;
}
```

Hopefully we will have `std::optional` soon, although it has been postponed from C++14.

These methods of retrieval require no need to copy the value from the map. Returning via out parameter implies making a copy of the value. I guess it depends on what your requirements are.

Comment: The boost suggestion is good. In the end, I opted away from it, just to keep the return value a string to simplify the usage. In this particular application, empty string is a reasonable return value to imply emptiness.  (In many other cases though, `boost::optional` would be the only way to go.)  Thanks for the ideas.